# iframe keeps on opening link on another tab when trying to play video

Tags: html, css, web, iframe

I have a iframe in my web page of a video from another site but when i click play or anywhere in the iframe space it opens a link to the site with the video  of it.

I'm trying to make a site for playing series and i want to use iframe to show the video from another site rather than downloading it.

I've tried everything but i viewed the other sites source code and it seems it has some java code i suppose that's causing the issue preventing the iframe from working.

http://entervideo.net/watch/94c96f7dc0bd33c

that's the link above, could you kindly inspect the source code first.

This is the code that I tried:

```
<iframe style ="display:block; margin: 0 auto;" width="1238" height="696" 
allowfullscreen="" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" 
frameborder="0" src="http://entervideo.net/watch/94c96f7dc0bd33c" 
scrolling="no"  target="_self"></iframe>
```

(Down below is the java script code from the link and I think it's causing the problem)

```
<script>
function inIframe () {
    try {
        return window.self !== window.top;
    } catch (e) {
        return true;
    }
}
console.log(document.referrer);

console.log(inIframe());
//if(!document.referrer&&inIframe()) document.write('<a 
href="http://entervideo.net/watch/94c96f7dc0bd33c" target="_blank" 
style="position:fixed; display:block; height:100%; width:100%; z-index:99999; 

    top: 0;left: 0; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);color:#fff;font-

size:30px;">Please remove sandbox tags on the iframe.</a>');

if(document.referrer||!inIframe()){

    var element = document.getElementById("ptc"); 

    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);

console.log('deleting');

}

</script>
```

i want it to play the video on my web page when i click on the play button on the control rather than it opening the link to the other site.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `target="_blank"` with `target="_self"` in JavaScript.

Comment: The thing is that JavaScript code is not from my site but the site I'm trying to use the iframe on.. so I can't change it

Comment: Create another script file after it and DOM get the element and change target from _blank to _self.